# how to change the background color of the div element using javascript value comparison?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I want to change the background color of the div element in table, based on the database value which is in json array.

Comment: can you show some code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

how is your json array looks like? it is not a good pattern to use, but you can give your div a style attribute and pass it your background color (if you have to do it dynamically through js).

Answer (score 0):

See here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrosxf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Assuming you know how to bring data from the database to angular. here is an example you can lern from...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: "<div [ngStyle]=\"{'background': data.color}\">some data</div>",
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data : {};

  constructor(){
    this.data = {"color" : "red"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngStyle** directive to apply style values like color:red , font-size .... , or  **ngClass** directive to apply one or more css classes

Examples

```
  colors = [
    {color:'red'},
    {color:'green'},
    {color:'blue'},
  ]

  classes =[
    {_class:'light'},
    {_class:'bold'},
    {_class:'orange'},
    {_class:'light-blue light bold'},
  ]
```

template

```
Colors - ngStyle
<div *ngFor="let c of colors" [ngStyle]="{color:c.color}">
  {{c.color}}
</div>
<br>

Classes - ngClass
<div *ngFor="let c of classes" [ngClass]="c._class">
 {{c._class}}
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcm1em)